# Can we generate iOS universal binary file (armv7 + arm64) with Delphi Alexandria?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Can we generate iOS universal binary file (armv7 + arm64) with Delphi Alexandria ? when I read this documentation: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store look like yes but I can't find the option " Generate iOS universal binary file (armv7 + arm64)" in project options > Delphi Compiler > Compiling > Other options (Delphi)

[image]

Comment: Did you try looking under [Project > Options > **Building** > Delphi Compiler > Compiling > Other Options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiling)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes but can't find this option under Alexandria :( I added a screenshot of what I see in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the right place but you forgot to change the target field in Project Options to `iOS Device 64 bit - All configurations` as it is mentioned on Embarcadero website.

If you have 32 bit target selected in project options (which is by default) the mentioned option isn't even shown.

Comment: But I can't find this option under Alexandria :( Iedited the question and added a screenshot of what I see in it

Comment: Then I guess you should report this to Embarcadero as possible bug. Or perhaps this is now enabled by default since Embarcadero on their web page claims: `Compile for macOS (M-series Apple Silicon) and use the new universal package for AppStore submission. You can now compile for both existing Intel and new M-series macOS processors (Apple Silicon). Compiling for the newest processor versions enables the fastest performance across all platforms, and supports universal packaging for the macOS app store.`

Comment: @silverWarrior It's will be very bad if this is enabled by default, because for exemple for external library you need to provide 32 version of those libraries that is not always suitable as 32 bit is not deprecated on iphone